# Check the repeated words in a string and keep a count in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to find repeated words in a string and keep a count of how many times it was repeated. 
How do I do it in javascript.

```js
 let checkWords = "I am not gonna live forever, but I wanna live while I am alive";
```

I am looking for output like this **I = 3**, **am = 2**, **not = 1** and so on, also is it possible to find the individual letter as **I = 3**, **a = 6**, **m = 2**.

I found a similar answer which I tried to use in my string, which works too but can anyone explain me why is the obj and undefined used here

```js
let str = "I am not gonna live forever, but I wanna live while I am alive",
    split = str.split(" "),
    obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
  if (obj[split[i]] === undefined) {
    obj[split[i]] = 1;
  } else {
    obj[split[i]]++;
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting occurrences of a word in a string Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914046/counting-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-string-javascript)

Comment: Yes the question is similar but I am hoping for a bit detail in the answer.

Comment: There are many other dupes to look at as this is a very common operation. Search term: "js word frequency count". If you're looking for a bit of detail in the answer, you'll need to add a bit of detail in the question. There's no attempt here--it's customary to show a [mcve]. Please see [ask].

Comment: @ggorlen  Thank you but your help didn't helped me.

Comment: the object is used here to distinguish the words in the way that the key is the word and the value is the number of its occurrences.
`obj[split[i]] === undefined` is used to check if the object contains the word that comes from the array: `split[i]`

Comment: @zb22 Thanks... Understood that solves my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly convert the given string to an array. To do that use `string.split("")`.

Secondly, create an `map` which will store word as key and count as value.

Now iterate through the stringArray and store the current word to the map. And increase the count for the word each time the word is found.

Check the below code.

```js
let words = "I am not gonna live forever, but I wanna live while I am alive";

function countRepeatedWords(sentence) {
  let words = sentence.split(" ");
  let wordMap = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    let currentWordCount = wordMap[words[i]];
    let count = currentWordCount ? currentWordCount : 0;
    wordMap[words[i]] = count + 1;
  }
  return wordMap;
}

console.log(countRepeatedWords(words));
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

```
let checkWords = "I am not gonna live forever, but I wanna live while I am alive"

const newStr = checkWords.split(' ').reduce((acc,rec) => {
  return ({ ...acc, [rec]: (acc[rec] || 0) + 1 })
},{})

const newStr2 = checkWords.split('').reduce((acc,rec) => {
  return ({ ...acc, [rec]: (acc[rec] || 0) + 1 })
},{})
```

{newStr} for counter words
{newStr2} for counter letters

Comment: ({ ...acc, [rec]: (acc[rec] || 0) + 1 } 

Can you explain this part, please

Comment: @Zeba spread operator ...acc, rec its elemets array newStr, if acc[rec] not undefined or null go to +1 or 0. i cannot explain about reduce, but all magic makes reduce here. if my answer helps you, please check my answer

Comment: and acc[rec] watch repeat elemets in our acc

Answer (score 0):

How to count the number of times each word appears in a string:

1. strip punctuation from the string with `.replace()`
2. change all character to lowercase with `.toLowerCase()`
3. convert string into array of words with `.split()`
4. loop through each word (`.forEach`), adding it to a word count object

```js
const result = document.getElementById('result');

let str = "I am not gonna live forever, but I wanna live while I am alive.";

// strip all punctuation from string
let strStripped = str.replace(/[,.!]/g, '');
result.innerHTML = `strStripped: "${strStripped}"\n`;

// separate string into array of lowercase words
let words = strStripped.toLowerCase().split(' ');
result.innerHTML += 'words: ' + JSON.stringify(words, null, 2);

// form object of word counts
let wordCounts = {};
words.forEach(word => {
  wordCounts[word] = (wordCounts[word] || 0) + 1;
});
result.innerHTML += '\nwordCounts: ' +
  JSON.stringify(wordCounts, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```